# titanium Map.Annotation Latitude , Longitude not changing after drag?

Tags: annotations, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've 1 `annotation` inside the map to select a place , **after drag and drop** the annotation i should take the new annotation lang,lat , **however after drag and drop the annotation the lang , lat still show the old credentials** .

---

> i am not able to get new annotation credentials , any idea ?

```
var MapModule = require('ti.map');
var mapView = MapModule.createView({
    mapType : MapModule.TERRAIN_TYPE,
    height : '50%',
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    top : 1,
    zoom : 12,
    region : {
        latitude : 33.373296399867975,
        longitude : 44.35598730468746,
        latitudeDelta : 0.6,
        longitudeDelta : 0.6
    },
    userLocation : true,
    animate : true,
    annotations : []
});
win.add(mapView);

annotation = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude : dalel.latitude,
    longitude : dalel.longitude,
    title : L('long_press_then_move'),
    subtitle : L('drag_drop_anotion'),
    draggable : true,
});
mapView.annotations = [annotation];
```

and here how i get lang lat of the annotation :

```
data.longitude = mapView.annotations[0].longitude;
data.latitude  = mapView.annotations[0].latitude;
```

Answer (score 1):

I never got exactly that to work :-(

Instead I implemented a "long click" event to set the annotation in a new place and remove the old one. And it actually turns out that this is better also from the user's perspective as it can sometimes be difficult to drag the annotation - especially if you need to drag it near the edges of the visible map or even beyond.

So I suggest you consider that option. Whether it will work for you is obviously dependent on the functionality of your app.

/John

Answer (score 0):

To receive the new location of the dragged pin listen to the [pinchangedragstate](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.View-event-pinchangedragstate) event of the Map View.

Comment: this event cost application crash , verified on JIRA https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20606?jql=text%20~%20%22pinchangedragstate%22